# Compute Fourier Series from Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am trying to get the coefficients of the classical Fourier Series from Mathematica's Fourier Transform.

Now as I understand, Mathematica provides the Fourier Series coefficients:

```
f[x_]:=Cos[t]

Table[{n, FourierCoefficient[f[t], t, n]}, {n, 0, 3}]

{{0, 0}, {1, 1/2}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}
```

I should be able to retrieve the coefficients from the Discrete Fourier Transform:

```
NN = 10
dt = (2 Pi/NN)
min = -Pi
max = Pi - dt

(* samples *)
fd = Table[N[{t, f[t]}], {t, min, max, dt}]

(* DFT *)
Fd = Chop[Fourier[fd[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]]

{0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5}
```

How can I write a function that gives as an output something similar to the `Table` of `FourierCoefficient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several pitfalls here. First, plot the data you use for the Fourier coefficients (note, only the y values are used. The x values are assumed to be 0,1,2,..):

```
f[x_] := Cos[t];
NN = 10;
dt = (2 Pi/NN);
min = -Pi;
max = Pi - dt;
fd = Table[N[f[t]], {t, min, max, dt}];
ListPlot[fd]
```

[image]

You see, this is -Cos not Cos. Therefore, for a comparison, you need to Fourier transform of -Cos:

```
f[t_] := -Cos[t];
Fd = Chop[Fourier[fd, FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]]

{0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.5}
```

Note that the firs coefficient belongs to the constant part (zero frequency), the second to the pos. lowest freq.,.., the sixth to the highest freq. and the last to the negative lowest frequency)

Second, for a Fourier series, you not only need the positive frequencies, but also the negative ones. That means you need the coefficients from -3,-2...0..3:

```
f[t_] := Cos[t];    
Table[{n, FourierCoefficient[f[t], t, n]}, {n, -3, 3}]
    
{{-3, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {0, 0}, {1, -(1/2)}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}
```

Now you see that the coefficients No. -1 and 1 correspond to the neg. and pos. freq. coefficients of the Fourier transform.

```
Addendum
```

Note that Fourier with FourierParameters {-1,1} is defined with base sequence Exp[2Pi I r s] and FourierCoefficient with default parameters with base functions Exp[-2Pi I n t]. Note the minus sign. For a comparision, you must use matching base functions.

Comment: Did you mean `f[t_]:=Cos[t]`. It didn’t make any difference in your table because t wasn’t defined—but I’m guessing that that was a typo.

Comment: Thanks, it is  corrected.

Comment: @DanielHuber thank you, you've been quite helpful! If I put min=0 and max=2 Pi it works with`Cos`, however, when trying `Sin`, I get swapped signs: the series gives these freq/coeff pairs`{{-5., 0.}, {-4., 0.}, {-3., 0.}, {-2., 0.}, {-1., 0. + 0.5 I}, {0., 0.}, {1., 0. - 0.5 I}, {2., 0.}, {3., 0.}, {4., 0.}, {5., 0.}}` while the transform `{{0, 0}, {1, 0. + 0.5 I}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 0}, {5, 0}, {-5, 0}, {-4, 0}, {-3, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-1, 0. - 0.5 I}}`. Is it possible that I need to use `FourierParameters` in the series?

Comment: But it is correct: `{0, 0. + 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 0.5 I}{-1., 0. + 0.5 I} ` corresponds to  `{{-3, 0}, {-2, 0}, {-1, I/2}, {0, 0}, {1, -(I/2)}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}}`

Comment: I am sorry @DanielHuber, I might be tired but I don't see them equal... for `Fd = Chop[Fourier[fd[[All, 2]], FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}]]` I get `{0, 0. + 0.5 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. - 0.5 I}`, so positive for the positive frequency and negative for negative ones. But `fs = Table[FourierCoefficient[f[t], t, n], {n, -M, M}]` gives me `{0, 0, 0, 0, I/2, 0, -(I/2), 0, 0, 0, 0}` with negative for the positive frequency and positive for the negative one... it seems I see inverted signs. What am I not seeing here?

Comment: Fourier with FourierParameters {-1,1} is defined with base sequence Exp[2Pi I r s] and FourierCoefficient with default parameters with base functions Exp[-2Pi I n t]. Note the minus sign.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for the clarification! Is it possible to have the two match? Or convert coefficients to match? It seems that `Fourier` with `FourierParameters -> {-1, 1}` yields the same coefficients as `FourierCoefficient` with `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}`, but I am not sure I have it right in a general case...

Comment: Yes, you must match the base functions, either both with a neg. sign or pos.

Comment: @DanielHuber thanks! If you update the answer I can mark it as resolved. Thank you!